# Why is scale of image different in QGIS 3.10 than created?. CAD import and twf world file seems correct

Tags: qgis-3, georeferencing, pyqgis-3, scale

I created an image by taking a picture of a tape measure(ruler).  I rotated this image to north and made a world file .tfw for the tiff image.  to get the pixel width for the twf file, I divided the measured width (1.308 meters) by the pixels in the image 1920.  This resulted in 0.00068125 m/pix. I used pyproj with EPSG:3857 to get the upper left corner of the image from the GPS location of where the image was created.  When I bring this into QGIS with projection 3857 it measures smaller by a factor of 0.705.   When I bring it into a cad system, it is correct.

I am using QGIS version 3.10.3-A Coruña on a Windows system. EPSG:3857.

Is there something I need to turn on or scale with QGIS?

**EDIT**
By just scaling the pixel width number by the cosine of the latitude (from the suggestion below) in the world file this seems to solve the issue for now.

Comment: That suggests you live at about 45° North (or South) - EPSG:3857 distorts distances by a factor of cos(lat)

Comment: Yes - Nearly 45.5 degrees. I had read this from here (http://www.klokan.cz).  Should I re-project this to something else to eliminate the distortion or scale the image before i XYZ tile it for a Leaflet viewer?

Answer (score 1):

You are measuring the ellipsoidal distance in QGIS but the planimetric or cartesian one in your cad system.

Also, you can measure the planimetric distance in QGIS and get the same value as in the cad system.

But the real problem is that a measure tape is not projected into reality with EPSG:3857 system, so the best solution is to adopt some reference system closer to the measure tape reality to be able to measure ellipsoidal distances, since you want to publish it georreferenced.

A respetable solution is to convert the geographic coordinate to a transverse mercator system centered in your location and then reproject it to EPSG:3857 to publish (if you need to publish with that reference). Also, if you use the corresponding predefined UTM zone, the distortion is not too big.

The difference between the real surface where the tape is located and the ellipsoidal reference surface where its coordinates are defined, is isually little than the tolerance of the work. If you need to get an excesive good representation of the reality, must include a third dimension and measure 3D cartesian distances instead of ellipsoidal nor planimetric ones.